# d-flex align-items-start is not working in bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

i am trying to align nav-items top of the navbar using **d-flex align-items-start** but its not working and its showing center to the navbar how can i do this can some one help me please

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light admin-header fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/karvy-logo.png" class="img-fluid logo"></a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav bg-primary d-flex align-items-start">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: visit [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#align-items) link first and check how area `ul` cover

Comment: @Nisharg Shah i already seen that and followed same way but not working

Comment: Is that the code for the entire Navbar? Is there other CSS?

Comment: @Zim there is for sure other css, there is no sush admin-header css class in bootstrap-4. 
Krish can you post your custom css

Comment: What do you mean "align nav-items top of the navbar"  ?